# Synchronized thread get/create via factory

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, concurrenthashmap

I want to have multiple threads, each of them linked to a "group", which will do operations. Each of these threads, will in a loop look into a queue of Operations to do, and it is not empty, they will take next Operation and process it.

It is as simple as this:

```java
public class GroupThreadManager {
        private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, GroupThread> threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        private synchronized static void newOperation(Operation op) throws IOException {
            final Long idGroup = op.getIdGroup();
            if (!threads.containsKey(idGroup )) {
                threads.put(idGroup , new GroupThread());

            }
            threads.get(idGroup ).start(op);
        }

        private synchronized static void interrupThread(Long id) {
            if(threads.remove(id) == null) {
                log.info("THIS SHOULDNT HAVE HAPPENED!!!!!");
            }
        }
}

public class GroupThread implements Runnable {
        private Thread worker;

        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Operation> operations = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        private Long idGroup;

        public void start(Operation op) throws IOException {
            addOperation(op);
            if (worker == null) {
                idGroup = op.getIdGroup();
                worker = new Thread(this);
                worker.start();
            }
        }

        public synchronized void addOperation(Operation op) {
            operations .add(user);
        }

        private synchronized int size() {
            return operations.size();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (size() > 0) {
                operations.poll()
                .compute() // do something here
            }
            GroupThreadManager.interrupThread(idUser);
        }
}
```

If the `run` method was implemented with `while (true)` I would have no problem. The issue comes when I want that thread to process all the operations it has, and whenever it becomes out of operations, I want to make that Thread end. I have been trying to make proper synchronization to create/get the Thread from the GroupThreadManager, but I always come into either deadlocks, either Thread ending with new Operations to proceed due to missing synchronization.

The idea is that from another part of the program I can just call `GroupThreadManager.newOperation(new Operation())` and this manager automatically gives me the correct thread for that groupId (contained in Operation), creating it, giving me the existing one, or stopping & deleting it when it detects there are no new operations for it

Comment: Are you sure you want to divide **threads** into groups? Why? Why can't any **free** thread do your job instead?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Yes, I need to divide them into groups. The reason is that each group  needs to process those Operations in order. If I do not do it like this, it might happen that `Operation2` for `Group1` gets executed earlier than `Operation1`

Comment: Can you modify `run()` to remove `GroupThreadManager.interrupThread(idUser)`? Once `size()` reaches 0, just let the run method exit. That looks like it would satisfy "whenever it becomes out of operations, I want to make that Thread end". If you later encounter a new need for that thread, create a new one.